# CSS Firefox Link is disappearing after click without redirecting

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have 1 simple link that works in every other browser but when clicking it on Firefox instead of redirecting the text for the link just disappears.

```css
a:focus {
  display: block;
}

.ICInformationLayer_wrapper .ic-info-layer-banner {
  min-height: 0 !important;
}

.MinibottomCopy {
  background-color: #e5ebce;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2% 0 2% 0;
}

.MinibottomCopy a {
  color: #000 !important;
}

.hide-mobile {
  display: block !important;
}

.show-mobile {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="MinibottomCopy">
  <a href="/xxx/shop/514535" class="ic-info-layer-learn-more-link">Learn More</a> about Benefits
</div>
```

Comment: CSS alone, without any HTML it is supposed to apply to, tells us rather little. Please present a proper [mre] when asking about issues like this.

Comment: @CBroe The post just needed some editing

Comment: I don't think is relevant, is just a simple text link that works fine in every browser but in Firefox the text disappears and the clickable area goes up to the whole image. Wondering if there's something I should know about Firefox

Comment: In the example above, the link "disappears" for me in a Chromium-based browser as well - of course, because clicking it causes a new page to load. _"and the clickable area goes up to the whole image"_ - what image? I really can't tell what the actual problem is supposed to be here.

Comment: For me too of course I just get a blank page whatever browser I use as I don't have the full URL. Are you sure that this isn't a page which for example requires the user to be logged in and that you've logged in on one browser at some point and not on FF? This is of course just a guess. If you put the full URL into your snippet we could have a further look.